# first load of the page gives 404 error

Tags: multisite, permalinks, 404-error

I'm having problem loading the page first time on my browser.

For example if I load the page from a link it gives me 404 error but when I refresh the page It works perfectly.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? Can you post an example link? Does this happen for any type of page, or only on single posts, archives, home pages etc.? What plugins are you running? What server are you running?

Comment: It gives 404 on random pages that you click. Its hard to trace because its not only on one page or two. I'm using bluehost. Its still on development Im not sure if I can post the link of the site here.

Comment: Is the 404 handled by WordPress or the server? (what does the resulting page look like & is there any error message?)

Comment: its handled by wordpress. the custom 404 page created with the theme that i'm using. Is this an htaccess problem?

Comment: Are you using an XML sitemap plugin by chance?